# FloodFill algorithm fills beyond the specified boundries

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, flood-fill

i want to floodFill a certain area "the rectangle on the left side" of the image posted below. to floodFill that area, i specified a point inside that rectangle to know the value of the pixel as follows:

```
    Log.D(TAG, "", "PixVal: "+gsMat.get(100, 240)[0]);//at that position the pixVal is 91 up ok
    Log.D(TAG, "", "PixVal: "+gsMat.get(250, 60)[0]);//at that position the pixVal is 217 l ??peoblem
    Log.D(TAG, "", "PixVal: "+gsMat.get(330, 310)[0]);//at that position the pixVal is 123 down ok
    Log.D(TAG, "", "PixVal: "+gsMat.get(330, 580)[0]);//at that position the pixVal is 84 r ok
```

and i am sure that point(x= 60, y= 250) lays inside that rectangle on the left. and i wrote the below code to folldfill that area. but i got the images posted below as result

```
"Mat subbed = gsRawMat.submat(r)" shows the whole orignal image as if the the whole pixel values in the image lays within the range of 216 to 218?

"ImageUtils.showMat(subbed, "subbed");" shows a white image as if the the whole pixel values in the image lays within the range of 216 to 218, hence, the whole area painted in white (255)?
```

please let me know why such behavior occurs

**Code**:

```
    Mat m = new Mat();
    Rect r = new Rect();
    Imgproc.floodFill(gsMat,
            m,
            new Point(60, 250),
            new Scalar(255),//to fill the designated area with color(255)
            r,//the rect that will encompass the designated area
            new Scalar(216),//lower bound
            new Scalar(218),//upper bound
            Imgproc.FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE);

    Mat subbed = gsRawMat.submat(r);// to extract the rectangle contains the flooded area from the main image
    ImageUtils.showMat(gsMat, "gsMat");//to show the gsmat
    ImageUtils.showMat(subbed, "subbed");//to show the subbed area from the gsMat
```

**results gsMat**:
[image]

**result subbed mat**:
[image]

Comment: It would help a lot if you included the result since your description seems a bit blurry to me.

Comment: @runDOSrun please have a look at the quest. i updated the entire question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this function, but according to the (C++) documentation, the parameters are not "lower bound" and "upper bound", but "lower difference" and "upper difference". Their brightness/color values are relative to the seed point x= 60, y= 250. I haven't had time to think it through, but could that be responsible?

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill